# RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError in cucumber routing issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, capybara, bdd, rspec-expectations

I started working on BDD through cucumber. (using Rails-3, gem 'cucumber-rails')
I want to redirect to user profile page (/users/id) when successful login.
I defined in controller as (redirect_to user_path(@user)) and the same thing I defined in cucumber as (page.current_path.should == user_path(@user))

In my step_definition

```
Given /^a user visits the signin page$/ do
  visit signin_path
end

When /^he log in as "(.*)\/(.*)"$/ do |email, password|
  @email = email
  fill_in "email", with: email
  fill_in "password", with: password
  click_button "Login"
end

Then /^he should see a signin link$/ do
  page.should have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path)
end

Then /^he should see his profile page$/ do
  @user = User.where("email = ?", @email)
  page.current_path.should == user_path(@user)
end
```

In my controller

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

 def create
  @user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email].downcase)
  if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
   sign_in @user      
   redirect_to user_path(@user)               
  else
   flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
   render 'new'
  end
 end
end
```

Now when running cucumber, I am getting this error:

```
expected: "/users/%23%3CActiveRecord::Relation:0x000000062fbec0%3E"
       got: "/users/4" (using ==) (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
```

In my features/support/env.rb:

```
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../../config/environment')
require 'cucumber/rails'
require 'rspec/expectations'
```

please answer where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code in your step definition is the problem:

```
Then /^he should see his profile page$/ do
  @user = User.where("email = ?", @email)
  page.current_path.should == user_path(@user)
end
```

`User.where` will always return a relation, even if the result is only one User record, hence the `ActiveRecord::Relation` part of your error message.

If you can be sure there will only be one User returned, you can swap it out for something like `User.find_by_email(@email)` or `User.where(:email => @email).first`, to get a single User instance.

Comment: thnx sevenseacat.....it solved my problem.
And the line `User.where will always return a relation, even if the result is only one User record, hence the ActiveRecord::Relation part of your error message` will also be more useful for me in future. :)